# Correlating resources in a XACML JSON request / response

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I am trying to evaluate the XACML request using the REST API. I use JSON requests to get the decisions for all resources under "root". WSO2 gives me the results, but I don't get the corresponding resources in the result

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+REST+APIs+via+XACML+to+Manage+Entitlement

### XACML Request in JSON Format

```js
{
    "Request": {
        "Action": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "POST"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "root"
                }, {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:resource:scope",
                    "Value": "Children"
                }
            ]
        },
        "AccessSubject": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id",
                    "Value": "customer"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### XACML Response in JSON Format

```js
{
    "Response": [{
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "Decision": "Permit",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0: status: ok "
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get the resource for any of the results. How will I correlate the results ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong in your request.

First of all you are trying to use the *Multiple Decision Profile of XACML* (i.e. a means to ask multiple questions in one go and get multiple responses back at once). You are using a special attribute called `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:resource:scope xacml`. That attribute belongs in fact to the older version of the *Multiple Decision Profile of XACML* called the [Multiple resource profile of XACML v2.0](https://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/2.0/MULTIPLE-PROFILE/access_control-xacml-2.0-mult-profile-spec-os.html). This is your first mistake. The JSON profile for XACML is only for XACML 3.0. Therefore you cannot use an older profile that is for XACML 2.0 only. Where did you find this example?

Secondly, let's assume for a second that the request did go through. Your request, as it is written, should never trigger a multiple decision response. It should either fail or return a single response. That's because you have not indicated the children in your resource attribute. So there is no way you should be able to get a response.

Going forward, I recommend you read up on the [JSON Profile of XACML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-json-http/v1.0/xacml-json-http-v1.0.html) which explains how to produce multiple decisions requests and responses. Here is an example:

- Can Alice edit, view, and delete doc #123?

```js
{
    "Request": {
        "AccessSubject": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "com.axiomatics.username",
                    "Value": "Alice"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Action": [{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "view"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "edit"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "delete"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "123"
                }, {
                    "AttributeId": "resource-type",
                    "Value": "document"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the response:

```js
{"Response": [
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }}
   },
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }}
   },
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }}
   }
]}
```

### Correlating responses

Now, if you want to correlate the requests with the responses, each attribute has a flag called `IncludeInResult` which is `false` by default and can be switched to `true`.

Here is an example

#### Request

```
{
    "Request": {
        "AccessSubject": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "com.axiomatics.username",
                    "Value": "Alice"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Action": [{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "view",
                    "IncludeInResult": true
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "edit",
                    "IncludeInResult": true
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "delete",
                    "IncludeInResult": true
                }
            ]
        }],
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "123"
                }, {
                    "AttributeId": "resource-type",
                    "Value": "document"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

#### Response

```
{"Response": [
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }},
      "Category":       {
         "CategoryId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action",
         "Attribute":          {
            "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
            "Value": "delete",
            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         }
      }
   },
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }},
      "Category":       {
         "CategoryId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action",
         "Attribute":          {
            "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
            "Value": "edit",
            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         }
      }
   },
      {
      "Decision": "Deny",
      "Status": {"StatusCode":       {
         "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
         "StatusCode": {"Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}
      }},
      "Category":       {
         "CategoryId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action",
         "Attribute":          {
            "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
            "Value": "view",
            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         }
      }
   }
]}
```

Comment: Even If I use IncludeInResult, I didn't got the corresponding values in response. Request is --> { "Request": { "Action": { "Attribute": [ { "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id", "Value": "POST", "IncludeInResult": true} ] }, "Resource": { "Attribute": [ { "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id", "Value": "root", "IncludeInResult": true } ] }, "AccessSubject": { "Attribute": [ { "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id", "Value": "customer", "IncludeInResult": true } ] } } }

Comment: and the response is  {"Response":[{"Decision":"Deny","Status":{"StatusCode":{"Value":"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"}}}]}

Comment: Well that tells you that WSO2IS does not comply to the XACML 3.0 spec :-)

Comment: No, JSON is not working for me ! Instead, I switched to XML.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2-IS is fully supported to the XACML 3.0 spec with XML. With IS 5.6.0 Milestone 2, WSO2 is supporting multi-decision profile with JSON

Comment: Who is "we" in this context?

Comment: Here are some blogs to go :[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Access+Control+and+Entitlement+Management#AccessControlandEntitlementManagement-JSONSupportwithXACML3.0
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Fine-grained+Authorization+using+XACML+Requests+in+JSON+Format
[3] https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/we-are-now-supporting-multi-decision-profile-in-json-8ddaba1fbed1

Answer (score 0):

If you try a XACML JSON request should looks like below:

```
 {
   "Request": {
      "http://wso2.org/identity/user": [
      {
         "Attribute": [
            {
               "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
               "Value": "adminUser",
                "IncludeInResult": true,
                "DataType": "string"
            }
         ]
      },{
         "Attribute": [
            {
               "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
               "Value": "publicUser",
                "IncludeInResult": true,
                "DataType": "string"
            }
         ]
      }  ],

      "Resource": {
         "Attribute": [
            {
               "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
               "Value": "index.jsp",
                "IncludeInResult": true,
                "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Action": [{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "view-welcome",
                     "IncludeInResult": true,
                     "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "view-status",
                     "IncludeInResult": true,
                     "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "view-summary",
                     "IncludeInResult": true,
                     "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "Attribute": [{
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "modify-welcome",
                     "IncludeInResult": true,
                     "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                }
            ]
        } ] 
   }
}
```

The relevant response will be as follows,

```
{
    "Response": [
        {
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Obligations": [
                {
                    "Id": "fail_to_permit",
                    "AttributeAssignments": [
                        {
                            "AttributeId": "obligation-id",
                            "Value": "You can not access the resource index.jsp",
                            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "adminUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-status",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Obligations": [
                {
                    "Id": "fail_to_permit",
                    "AttributeAssignments": [
                        {
                            "AttributeId": "obligation-id",
                            "Value": "You can not access the resource index.jsp",
                            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "adminUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-summary",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Permit",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-welcome",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "publicUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Permit",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-summary",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "publicUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Obligations": [
                {
                    "Id": "fail_to_permit",
                    "AttributeAssignments": [
                        {
                            "AttributeId": "obligation-id",
                            "Value": "You can not access the resource index.jsp",
                            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "adminUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-welcome",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Obligations": [
                {
                    "Id": "fail_to_permit",
                    "AttributeAssignments": [
                        {
                            "AttributeId": "obligation-id",
                            "Value": "You can not access the resource index.jsp",
                            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "view-status",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "publicUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Deny",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Obligations": [
                {
                    "Id": "fail_to_permit",
                    "AttributeAssignments": [
                        {
                            "AttributeId": "obligation-id",
                            "Value": "You can not access the resource index.jsp",
                            "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "modify-welcome",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "publicUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Decision": "Permit",
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": {
                    "Value": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
                }
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                        "Value": "index.jsp",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "http://wso2.org/identity/user": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username",
                        "Value": "adminUser",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Action": {
                "Attribute": [
                    {
                        "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                        "Value": "modify-welcome",
                        "IncludeInResult": "true",
                        "DataType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In multi-decision profile of XACML - the result will provide all the combinations of decisions that can take upon actions on an resource for specific subject or a resource owner.

"IncludeInResult", property will include these parameters in the response, you can shorten the response by making it false.

In WSO2 Identity server you have the ability to add custom categories like "http://wso2.org/identity/user" with a user claim as a AttributeId : like "http://wso2.org/identity/user/username"

WSO2 IS Multi-Decision Profile in JSON supports, bothe JSON simplified format as well ass XAML standard URI's  too. You can try both.

**eg: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id -> action-id**